# How to upload image through restful web services on server using Struts2 (error after deployed the server )

Tags: web-services, web, struts2

HOW TO RETURN IMAGE IN RESTFUL

I had uploaded image in database but when I deployed the project on server it should not display the image on JSP pages.

how should I do the services for the upload and I wanted to display on jsp pages.

```
  <action name="saveGrid" method="saveGrid"
        class="com.rssquarz.png.action.GridAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
        <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">image/x-png,image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg</param>
            <param name="maximumSize">922240</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="params">
            <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">Grid.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">Grid.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">Grid.jsp</result>
    </action>

public class GridDao {

public int saveGrid(Grid grid) {
    {
        SessionFactory factory = null;
        Session session = null;
        System.out.println("you are in saveGrid ");
        try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(grid);
            t.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```java
public class GridAction extends ActionSupport {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4964110302586165626L;
private List<Grid> listGrid;
Grid grid = new Grid();

private File fileUpload;

private String fileUploadContentType;

private String fileUploadFileName;

private String ImgURL;

public String saveGrid() {
    try {
        String resultUpload = saveImage();
        if (resultUpload.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

            String address = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            ImgURL = "http://" + address + ":8080/PngAppWebApp/temp/"
                    + fileUploadFileName;

            grid.setImageUrl(ImgURL);

            new GridDao().saveGrid(grid);

            return SUCCESS;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;

}

public String editGrid() {
    try {
        String resultUpload = saveImage();
        if (resultUpload.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

            String address = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

            ImgURL = "http://" + address + ":8080/PngAppWebApp/temp/"
                    + fileUploadFileName;

            grid.setImageUrl(getImgURL());

            new GridDao().editGrid(grid);
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;
}

public String saveImage() throws IOException {

    try {

        ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext
                .getServletContext();
        String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/temp");
        System.out.println("Server path:" + path);
        String filePath = servletContext.getRealPath(path);
        System.out.println("path:" + filePath);
        File uploadDir = new File(filePath, fileUploadFileName);
        // if the folder does not exits, creating it
        if (uploadDir.exists() == false) {
            uploadDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File destFile = new File(path, fileUploadFileName);
        FileUtils.copyFile(fileUpload, destFile);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String listGrid() {
    try {
        listGrid = new GridDao().listGrid();
        System.out.println("you are in ListUser");
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;
}

public String preprEditGrid() {
    try {

        grid = new GridDao().preprEditGrid(grid);
        System.out.println("you are in editUser" + grid);
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;
}

public String deleteGrid() {
    try {
        new GridDao().deleteGrid(grid);
        return SUCCESS;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;

}

public List<Grid> getListGrid() {
    return listGrid;
}

public void setListGrid(List<Grid> listGrid) {
    this.listGrid = listGrid;
}

public Grid getGrid() {
    return grid;
}

public void setGrid(Grid grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
}

public File getFileUpload() {
    return fileUpload;
}

public void setFileUpload(File fileUpload) {
    this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
}

public String getFileUploadContentType() {
    return fileUploadContentType;
}

public void setFileUploadContentType(String fileUploadContentType) {
    this.fileUploadContentType = fileUploadContentType;
}

public String getFileUploadFileName() {
    return fileUploadFileName;
}

public void setFileUploadFileName(String fileUploadFileName) {
    this.fileUploadFileName = fileUploadFileName;
}

public String getImgURL() {
    return ImgURL;
}

public void setImgURL(String imgURL) {
    ImgURL = imgURL;
}

}
```

Comment: I've removed your request to treat this urgently, for a second time. Please remember that all questions here are answered by volunteers, and that no question is more important than another.

Answer (score 0):

After the image is uploaded it's removed from the disk by Struts2.

When the image is stored to database it could be retrieved by the action for displaying purposes.

The image URL should be mapped to the action that returns an image via `stream` result. Make sure you specify the `image/*` content type properly.

Comment: but i had save the path in database ... after deploying the project on server its give the  problem (not display images on client machine )

Comment: After uploading an image it's destroyed from the disk. You have to copy the file to the folder from which you can serve the image.